# How change type of hard disk with the format command of SOLARIS

Tags: solaris, fdisk, zfs

I would like to change the type of disk form :

```
  15. c2t15d0 <Sun-STK RAID INT-V1.0 cyl 36417 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
      /pci@0,0/pci10de,375@f/pci108e,286@0/disk@f,0
```

to

```
  15. c2t15d0 <Sun-STK RAID INT-V1.0-278.99GB>
      /pci@0,0/pci10de,375@f/pci108e,286@0/disk@f,0
```

I tried several type in format command or copied partition table no issue.
I encountered  this problem  on this disk

```
fdisk /dev/rdsk/c2t15d0
fdisk: Cannot stat device /dev/rdsk/c2t15d0.
```

The other disk doesn't have any problem with the fdisk command applied directly

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you sure the disk is actually connected/available?  What happens if you try something like `dd if=/dev/dsk/c2t15d0 of=/dev/null` as root?

Comment: Which version of Solaris?

Comment: Solaris 10 with zfs

Comment: SPARC or x86?  For the most part they're identical, but handling of drives is different.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a stale device link.

You don't note your version of Solaris.  Usually a `devfsadm -Cv` will rebuild the tree and clean out any invalid links.

Although, now after rereading your question, I'm wondering if you want to see the "... 278.99GB" in format vs "... cyl, hd, and sec"?  If so, I believe it needs to have an EFI label.

Also after re-reading, noticed that you left off the slice in your `fdisk` commands.

NOTE/WARNING:  Changing between a SMI and EFI label can result in data loss.  You'll want to read up on the differences, and maybe test on another system prior to making the change using `format -e`.

Comment: There's also a `diskinfo` command which may be of use.

Comment: Yes I applied the EFI label with fdisk but no issue as fdisk want a number of partition. When I dared to add my disk in the zfs spare, the label has been written and the disk has got its EFI label. the problem has been  solved without more explanation

Comment: @dubis Not sure I fully follow.
  When you use the whole disk with a zpool command, zfs will label it with an EFI label and use the whole drive.
  I'm also begining to suspect your using the x86 version of Solaris.

Comment: I didn't repond your ask as IWas not notified Yes I'm using X86 so you're right. EFI on SPARK mother board is it possible ? Sound odd